# Update Response Headers of next.js Middleware Rewrite / Proxy

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using `next.js` [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) to proxy/rewrite some paths that should be handled by a different origin/host. This works great with one exception:

When the `rewrite` response is a `302` redirect, the `location` header contains the value:

- location header: `https://www.otherwebsite.com/page`
- desired header: `https://www.website.com/page`

In my situation, I cannot modify the proxied host. I need some way to sniff the response, and modify it before its returned to the user.

```js
// Assume all of this is running at `https://www.website.com`
// This middleware is applied to: `/some-path*`
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const headers = new Headers(request.headers);
    headers.set('Origin', `https://www.otherwebsite.com`);

    const updatedUrl = request.nextUrl.clone();
    updatedUrl.protocol = 'https';
    updatedUrl.host = 'www.otherwebsite.com';
    updatedUrl.port = '';

    return NextResponse.rewrite(updatedUrl, {
        // overrides request headers with the specified new ones.
        request: {
            headers,
        },
    });
};
```

**Potential Solutions**

I am actively investigating these, but encountering misc. issues. It's unclear to me if there's some obvious helper or pattern that I'm missing.

- Clone the `NextResponse` and make a node `fetch` call

  - If the `status` is a `302` or `301`, update the `location` header
- Find a way for the proxied host to use an extra request header to inform the returned `location` header's value